# Autofill in Android Oreo not working when app handles localization

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-autofill-manager

I can't seem to make the Autofill to show for an application that handles its own localization.

For some reason, if `attachBaseContext` is modified to configure localized resources, the Autofill simply won't work:

[image: if attachBaseContext is modified]

However, if the activity just has `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and nothing else, the Autofill works fine:

[image: without attachBaseContext]

Does anyone know why this happens? And how do I localize my app while allowing Autofill to run normally?

---

Below are some of the code for this test app.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        if (newBase != null) {
            // Switch the locale between "en" or "in"
            final Context newContext = wrapLocale(newBase, new Locale("en"));
            super.attachBaseContext(newContext);
        } else {
            super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
        }
    }

    private Context wrapLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
        final Resources res = context.getResources();
        final Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            final LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
            config.setLocales(localeList);
            config.setLocale(locale);
            return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, null);
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

*res/layout/activity_main.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sample_string" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autofillHints="name"
        android:hint="@string/sample_hint" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*res/values/strings.xml*

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AutofillAndLocale</string>
    <string name="sample_string">English</string>
    <string name="sample_hint">This is in English</string>
</resources>
```

*res/values-in/strings.xml*

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AutofillAndLocale</string>
    <string name="sample_string">Bahasa Indonesia</string>
    <string name="sample_hint">Pakai Bahasa Indo</string>
</resources>
```